# YouTubePlayer is stopped when changing fragments in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-youtube-api

I have application that using ViewPager with TabLayout and i have five diffrents tab which means five diffrents fragments. One of my fragments is using YouTubePlayer, Everything going well until i'm swiping to diffrent tab, when i'm swiping the tabs the player stop.
I tried to use:

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
```

And i can see that no onPause and onDestroyView have been called so i understand that the youtubeplayer is probably stopping himself.
Now my question is if there is a way to make that fragment live always and the video will keep running and sounding when my user is travel around my application's tab or its a problem with Youtube Terms of Service?
Its important to say that i'm giving all the credit in youtube and thats why i used YouTube API.

The YouTubePlayer fragmets code:

```
public class MusicFragment extends Fragment {
    YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
    private boolean isPlayerRunning = false;

    public MusicFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transcation = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transcation.add(R.id.music_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(HomeActivity.API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if(!b){
                    YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                    youTubePlayer.loadVideo(HomeActivity.VIDEO_ID);
                    youTubePlayer.play();
                    youTubePlayer.setManageAudioFocus(false);
                    isPlayerRunning = true;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

            }
        });
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_music, container, false);
    }

    public void runPlayer(){
        YPlayer.play();
    }
    public void pausePlayer(){
        YPlayer.pause();
    }

}
```